# Google Location API - Get location updates in fragment when app is in background

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-gps, google-location-services

I want to achieve kind of an GPS-Tracking in an android-application. 
For doing this, I have a `MainActivtity` which switches between different `Fragments`. One of them is the `HomeFragment`, whicht extends `android.app.Fragment` and contains an `MapView` and the `GoogleAPIClient.

I request the location updates with this code:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationHelper.LOCATION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MILLI);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationHelper.FASTEST_LOCATION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MILLI);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

So, if the app is running in foreground, I get the location updates as I desire. But if the app is in background, I don't get any updates anymore. I read that you have to explicitly tell the API to pause location updates by removing then in e.g. the onPause()-method, but I haven't done this and therefore expect them.

I also tried to implement a service for this, but later on read that the locations are already fetched in a service.
Furthermore, I can't imagine that this is even possible to work due to fragment/activity lifecycles.

Kind regards,
Force0234

Comment: Locations are fetched on a Service, sure, but your app needs a Service itself to listen to that other service in a long running process

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense...As I said, I also thought of this, but why is Google using a Activity for getting the location updates then? Because they do, and they even claim to get updates if the application is run in background-mode...

Comment: You attach a listener to get the Activity or Fragment to update the UI, sure. You also need an Activity or other Context to register a background service